# C# で Session 変数の内容を操作することは可能？

Tags: c#, asp.net

C# Sessionに関しての質問です。
Sessionに配列やコレクションを格納して保持したとします。

```
List<int> numlist = new List<int>();
Session["a"] = numlist;
```

この際に、Session["a"]内のnumlistに値を追加していくことは可能なのでしょうか？
いろいろと調べたのですが、配列やコレクションをSessionに格納できることはわかりましたが、
Session内の配列やコレクションを操作する方法がわからず困っています。

ご存じの方がいましたら、教えていただけると助かります。
よろしくしお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト https://teratail.com/questions/e4wendmcpooz54

Answer (score 1):

以下の記事を見ると直接操作するのは出来ないようですね。
[adding string array in existing session of array c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52479013/9014308)
[Using List Objects in a Session Variable](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fe3782d3-431e-40e1-8908-e35299de0853)

いずれの記事もSessionに変数が無ければ自分で作って代入する、変数が存在するならいったんローカルにコピーして必要な操作を行ってからSessionに代入するということを行っているようです。

---

**追記**

コメントで指摘されている`ASP.NET Core`の場合の方法は以下の記事が参考になると思われます。
[セッション値の設定および取得 - ASP.NET Core でのセッションと状態の管理](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0#set-and-get-session-values)

> セッション状態にアクセスするには、Razor Pages の PageModel クラスか、MVC の Controller クラスを HttpContext.Session と共に使用します。 このプロパティは ISession の実装です。
> ISession の実装では、整数値や文字列値を設定および取得するための複数の拡張メソッドが提供されています。 拡張メソッドは Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http 名前空間にあります。

ISessionのSet/Getの型を指定した拡張メソッドを実装してシリアライズ/デシリアライズを行うようです。

これの前後も含めてこのページ全体が`ASP.NET Core`でのSessionの取り扱いを解説しているのでしょう。

英語版サイトの関連記事：
[How to store list object in session variable using asp.net core. And how to fetch values from session variable from the View?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56833328/9014308)
[Define and obtain a list of ASP.Net Core (Session)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55269087/9014308)
[How to set different generic list value in same session in asp.net core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64065561/9014308)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。操作したい場合は一度、ローカル変数に代入して変更してからまた戻すといった方法しかなさそうですね。わかりやすいご説明ありがとうございます。とても助かりました。

Comment: kunif さん、そもそも List<int> が Session に保持できるとは限らないのですよ。

Comment: 一応、MSDNフォーラムの記事の方は List<int> の例を提示していてチェックマークが付いているので、何かしらの解決にはなっていそうですが、まあ確かに自分で確かめたわけでは無いのでダメかもしれませんね。

Comment: > 一応、MSDNフォーラムの記事の方は List<int> の例を提示 <=その記事は 2009 年と古いので .NET Framework 版の ASP.NET でしょう。ASP.NET Core の場合は Session に保存できるのは int, string, byte[] だけです。.NET Framework 版でも InProc 以外はシリアライズできることという制約があります。

Comment: なるほど、そういう違いがあって全てに適用出来るものでは無いということですか。そういう意味ではこの質問のタグはasp.netでasp.net-coreでは無いのでギリギリセーフかも？という所ですかね？

Comment: > ギリギリセーフかも？という所ですかね？ <=どうでしょう？ InProc はワーカープロセスのリサイクルで消えてしまうので、StateServer や SqlServer を使うことが多いようですが、その場合はシリアライズできることという制約があります。List<int> は大丈夫な気はしますが検証は必要かと。

Comment: ただ、何にせよ、回答の「変数が存在するならいったんローカルにコピーして必要な操作を行ってからSessionに代入する」は正しいです。

Answer (score 0):

プロパティを使えばいいと思います！

```
public List<string> NumList {
   get { return (List<string>) Session["a"]; }
   set { Session["a"] = value; }
}
```